# Communicate with neo4j server using async (or other) protocols than rest

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

We are willing to have neo4j on production.

I tried to look at the docs and understand if the way to communicate with neo4j only by REST or whether we have other protocols to do that?

We planning to have thousands of requests per sec and we worried that http rest wont be good for us as protocol.

Any clarification about that?
Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently only protocol which is supported by Neo4j is HTTP.

Neo4j version 3.0 will contains binary protocol.

---

REST is one option, you can choose drivers for your programming language

- http://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/

Comment: And how would you scale it?

Comment: thats HA.. I am talking about capacity/throughput